# Cluster configuration for cross join operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, amazon-emr

I am running a spark application in AWS EMR. The application involves performing an mllib function (columnSimilarities) on 300000 columns and a cross join operation. I got Out-Of-Memory error in my present cluster configuration when i ran it. My doubt is if i should increase the no of nodes or upgrade the instance type and keep the no of nodes the same. On another note, how do we decide on the memory size of the master node.Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try to increase the driver memory. e.g --driver-memory=8g